# I want to rename .dat files to some other extension and add some more extension to it

Tags: perl

I am new to perl.

I have few hundreds of file `IND1234-238772-20111010103010.DAT` and similar format
Now, I want to rename all files to new format:

```
ABC.SOME_STUFF_IND1234-238772-20111010103010.mbin
```

like: `addsome_ext<old_extension>.mbin`

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried using the `rename` command? `man rename`

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -e 'rename $_, "PRE_$_" for <*>'
```

with PRE_ being your prefix.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on a Unix-ish OS, and have the [rename](http://man.he.net/man1/rename) utility that comes with perl installed, you can just do:

```
rename 's/^(.*)\.DAT$/ABC.SOME_STUFF_$1.mbin/s' *.DAT
```

Alternatively, you can do this easily enough with pure Perl:

```
foreach my $old (<*.DAT>) {
    my $new = $old;

    $new =~ s/^(.*)\.DAT$/ABC.SOME_STUFF_$1.mbin/s or next;

    if (-e $new) {
        warn "Not renaming $old to $new, target file exists!\n";
        next;
    }
    rename $old, $new or warn "Error renaming $old to $new: $!\n"
}
```

Ps. The code above works if you run it in the directory containing the files.  If you want to run it from some other directory, you can either put an explicit

```
chdir 'C:/Mydir/testdir' or die "Could not change to target directory: $!\n";
```

in front of it, or change the glob to `<C:/Mydir/testdir/*.DAT>` and the regexp replacement to `s/^(.*[\\\/])(.*)\.DAT$/$1ABC.SOME_STUFF_$2.mbin/s`.

Comment: I want to search in a particluar directory say C:\Mydir\testdir\ and try to search all the file whose extension is .dat file then try to prefix name in the already file name.